# Error: int cannot be converted to int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, methods, integer

I was doing this question on HackerRank (Diagonal Difference) and I am currently facing an issue.

Here is the link to the question:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem

The problem is that I'm constantly getting an error: `int cannot be converted to int[][]`.
I tried initialising the variable j but that too is not solving the issue.

Here is my code:

```java
import java.util.*;
public class DiagonalDifference {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a[][] = new int[3][3]; //Initializing the array of 3X3

        //Assuming i: rows and j: columns
        int i, j, leftToRight = 0, rightToLeft = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        diagonalDiff(a[i][j], leftToRight, rightToLeft);
    }

    static int diagonalDiff(int a[][], int leftToRight, int rightToLeft) {
        leftToRight = a[0][0] + a[1][1] + a[2][2];
        rightToLeft = a[0][2] + a[1][1] + a[2][0];

        int diff = Math.abs(leftToRight - rightToLeft);
        return diff;
    }
}
```

If anyone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong, I'll be grateful.
Thank you.

Comment: Your solution will only work for arrays of size 3x3, in the problem they can be of variable size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `diagonalDiff` must be of type `int[][]`, while you pass it `a[i][j]`, which is the integer number in variable `a` at location `i, j`. So as the error says you are supplying an integer as an argument to a parameter of type "array of arrays of integers", which of course doesn't work.

If you want to pass a reference to the matrix to your method, you can change the way you call `diagonalDiff` to be:

```
diagonalDiff(a, leftToRight, rightToLeft)
```

Comment: Ok, I realised it now. So whenever I'm passing parameters, I should not pass the variables with it. Right?

Comment: @BlackWizard it all depends on what value you need to pass. If your method required an integer you could still have used `a[i][j]`. For instance, a valid call to the method would be `diagonalDiff(a, a[i][j], rightToLeft)`. Here you'd be passing a reference to the matrix `a`, the integer at position `i, j` within `a` and then `rightToLeft`. This works because `a[i][j]` resolves to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `diagonalDiff` method is an array (2-D). But you're passing an `int` while calling it. (`a[i][j]` will be an `int`)

try calling it this way:

```java
diagonalDiff(a, leftToRight, rightToLeft);
```

Once you do this, you might also not require initializing `j` before the loop.

---

Minor other suggestions/nitpick (not related to this question, but will help OP to learn):

- You might not want to pass `leftToRight` and `rightToLeft` to `diagonalDiff` because you're overwriting the passed values and computing them from scratch.
- You can write the loop as `for(int i=0; i<3; i++)` instead of declaring the int outside of loop. This is a more commonly followed convention.
- Good to declare `diagonalDiff` as `private` as it won't be used outside of this class.
- Looking like you're calling `diagonalDiff` but ignoring the value returned. You might want to use that value.
- You can directly return the calculated `diff` instead of storing it in a variable.

Comment: Excellent suggestions! I'll pay attention to them for sure. Thank you very much.

About the second point you made, I actually did not initialised the variables outside the loop in the first place. It was only because of the "variable j hasn't been initialised" error, I had to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to pass array to another methode we use array address for it.Array address is also known as array reference.
As a example :-

```
int a[][] = new int[3][3];
```

In this array array address is a.

So a[i][j] mean some element that you installed to (i,j).
So in your code ,

```
 diagonalDiff(a[i][j], leftToRight, rightToLeft);
```

a[i][j] argument is not pass any array.But your parameter is 2D type array.So compilar say  int cannot be converted to int[][].
So code should be ,

```
 diagonalDiff(a[i][j], leftToRight, rightToLeft);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your method diagonalDiff accepts an integer array of 2 dimensions but you are passing it a[i][j] which is one element of that array which is just an integer.